# How to upload apk file as binary field and download it with same file name in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I need a form which accept upload android .apk file. and download it with same name.

Here is what I start with

```py
# model.py
class AppVersion(models.Model):
  # ...
  apk_file = fields.Binary('Apk file', filters='*.apk', required=True)
```

But in odoo-14 the `filters` param is not work any more. It accept all kind files.

[image: odoo form accept all kind files]

And after upload complete, download button gives me a zip file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some source code research I found the solution:

## Issues 1: accpet .apk file only

Add a `options` attribute with `accepted_file_extensions` property into the binary field.

## Issues 2: download file with same name

Add a new char field in model to save the file name, bind it to binary field with `filename` attribute. and don't forget add the new field into form view (set to `invisible`)

## Code

```py
# model
class AppVersion(models.Model):
  # ...
  apk_file = fields.Binary('Apk file', store=True, attachment=False, required=True)
  apk_fname = fields.Char(string='File name')
```

```xml
<!--form view-->
<field name="apk_file" widget="binary" options="{'accepted_file_extensions': '.apk'}" filename="apk_fname"/>
<field name="apk_fname" invisible="1"/>
```

## Success result

[image: binary field with file name]